# complex search and replace strings with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

My problem: I need to delete and replace complex parts from a long HTML string.

Example:

```
// <div>
text = text.replaceAll("<div>", "");
```

This is not a problem. But div can also be `<div class="anything">`. How can I detect and replace such passages? So if a part that is between < and > is unknown?

Comment: You cannot parse XML using a regex, because what if the text contained inside an attribute value also contains a <> ?

Comment: Try using regex such as `text = text.replace(/<div.*?>/gi, "");`

Comment: This could be an XY problem, could you explain in more detail what your trying to achieve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454